# How to transfer a file to sftp using jsch using base64 encoding

Tags: java, base64, sftp, jsch

I am encoding my file into a base64 string. I want to transfer this to a sftp folder using JSch without creating a local file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably use the method

```
void put(InputStream src, String dst, SftpProgressMonitor monitor, int mode)
```

in class [ChannelSftp](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html). JSch also provides an [example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html) on how to set up and tear down an SFTP session.

Answer (score 0):

I Used `put(String src, String dst)` method in ChannelSftp class

```
private void getConnection(String username, String hostname, String password) {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel(CHANNEL_TYPE);
        channel.connect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void disconnectConnections() {
    if (channel.isConnected()) {
        channel.disconnect();
    }
    if (session.isConnected()) {
        session.disconnect();
    }
}

private String getConfiguration(String key) {
    return configuration.getString(key);
}

public void uploadToSftp(String sftpFileLocation, String fileToBeUploaded, String filename) {
    if (session == null || channel == null || !session.isConnected() || !channel.isConnected()) {
        getConnection(getConfiguration(USERNAME), getConfiguration(HOST), getConfiguration(PASSWORD));
    }
    try {
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(sftpFileLocation);
        byte[] data = BaseEncoding.base64().decode(fileToBeUploaded);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        channelSftp.put(is, filename);
        disconnectConnections();
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @shuti,
Can u pls showcase code for this scenario? awaiting for your response.

Comment: @Justin Sorry for the delay in replying, I have added the code snippet for the same